# FLEX mx:DataGridColumn decode HTML entities automatically

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I would like to show HTML entities that encoded in grid cell like this:

```
|HTML ENTITY|
 &lt;div&gt;
```

But the result is

```
|HTML ENTITY|
<div>
```

I used **mx:DataGridColumn**

Answer (score 0):

I tried this, for me its coming with encoded value only in grid please send your data provider format

```
[Bindable]
private var myGAC:ArrayCollection = new    
ArrayCollection([{label:"&lt;div&gt;"},{label:"&lt;div&gt;"},  
{label:"&lt;div&gt;"},{label:"&lt;div&gt;"},{label:"&lt;div&gt;"}]);

<mx:DataGrid id="myGrid" dataProvider="{myGAC}" width="500" rowCount="2">
<mx:columns>
<mx:DataGridColumn dataField="label" />
</mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```